# Paypal Express Checkout : Get Billing Agreement ID later

Tags: paypal

During a transaction with creation of billing agreement id using Paypal Express Checkout, if customer completes the payment on paypal page and the network between him and merchant disrupts when redirecting to merchant page. Will his card be charged even if `DoExpressCheckout` is not made? How to get transaction status along with billing Id after the token is expired for above scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Unless you call the DoExpressCheckout API , money is not going to be charged on the buyer's account .